# Installing a binary on a k8s virtual machine with Container-Optimized OS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

Pretty simple situation. I use container engine to create k8s clusters. I need to fuse some buckets to the nodes and want to use this project for that purpose:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse

I downloaded it and cross-compiled for linux as such:

```
gcsfuse_linux: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

When I do that and scp the pre-compiled go to the machine it gives me:

```
bash: ./gcsfuse_linux: Permission denied
```

Which is strange given I own the file, have the root and exec permission on the file.

Comment: Is the file system you're on mounted with `noexec`?

Comment: @yoonix Yes, you are right. They mount their filesystems with noexec by default.

Comment: @user3081519 Were you able to resolve it? If so, please post an self-answer so it can benefit the community in similar situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all other container-only philosophies (I am looking at you, CoreOS) the binaries are not supposed to be installed directly onto a virtual machine. Your best option is to create the container yourself and pull it from your source, then mount the filesystem of the virtual machine within it if you need it (or through the deployment using k8s).